# Apache spark Hive, executable JAR with maven shade

Tags: maven, apache-spark, datanucleus, maven-shade-plugin, spark-hive

I'm building apache-spark application with Apache Spark Hive. So far everything was ok - I've been running tests and whole application in Intellij IDEA and all tests together using maven.

Now I want to run whole application from bash and let it run with local single-node cluster. I'm using maven-shade-plugin to build single executable JAR.

Application crashes when it tries to create new HiveContext out of SparkContext. Thrown exception tells me that hive can't create metastore because there is some problem with datanucleus and its plugin system. I tried to follow several questions how to run datanucleus plugin system with shade but out of luck. For example: 
[Datanucleus, JDO and executable jar - how to do it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10096772/datanucleus-jdo-and-executable-jar-how-to-do-it)

What is the best way to compose executable JAR of application using hive and run it from bash? Perhaps some settings of datanucleus and its plugin system?

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>test</groupId>
    <artifactId>hive-test</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.7</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- spark -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-hive_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <properties>
        <!-- To be specified in child pom:  <main.class></main.class> -->
        <final.jar.name>${project.artifactId}-${project.version}</final.jar.name>
        <main.class>com.test.HiveTest</main.class>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <!-- the Maven compiler plugin will compile Java source files -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <!-- the Maven Scala plugin will compile Scala source files -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.scala-tools</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-scala-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.15.2</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>scala-compile-first</id>
                        <phase>process-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>add-source</goal>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <args>
                                <arg>-Xmax-classfile-name</arg>
                                <arg>110</arg>
                            </args>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>scala-test-compile</id>
                        <phase>process-test-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>testCompile</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <args>
                                <arg>-Xmax-classfile-name</arg>
                                <arg>110</arg>
                            </args>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <transformers>
                                <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                    <mainClass>${main.class}</mainClass>
                                </transformer>
                                <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                                    <resource>reference.conf</resource>
                                </transformer>
                                <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.XmlAppendingTransformer">
                                    <resource>plugin.xml</resource>
                                </transformer>
                                <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ServicesResourceTransformer"/>
                            </transformers>
                            <filters>
                                <filter>
                                    <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                                    <excludes>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                                    </excludes>
                                </filter>
                            </filters>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

**SampleCode**

```
object HiveTest {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    // Set up Spark
    val conf = new SparkConf(true)
      .setMaster("local")
      .setAppName("hive-test")

    println("Initializing spark context")
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)

    println("Initializing hive context")
    val hc = new HiveContext(sc)
  }
}
```

**Thrown exception**

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:522)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.ClientWrapper.<init>(ClientWrapper.scala:194)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.IsolatedClientLoader.createClient(IsolatedClientLoader.scala:238)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext.executionHive$lzycompute(HiveContext.scala:218)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext.executionHive(HiveContext.scala:208)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext.functionRegistry$lzycompute(HiveContext.scala:462)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext.functionRegistry(HiveContext.scala:461)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.UDFRegistration.<init>(UDFRegistration.scala:40)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext.<init>(SQLContext.scala:330)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext.<init>(HiveContext.scala:97)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext.<init>(HiveContext.scala:101)
        at com.test.HiveTest$.main(HiveTest.scala:21)
        at com.test.HiveTest.main(HiveTest.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.MetaStoreUtils.newInstance(MetaStoreUtils.java:1523)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.<init>(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:86)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.getProxy(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:132)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.getProxy(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:104)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.createMetaStoreClient(Hive.java:3005)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getMSC(Hive.java:3024)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:503)
        ... 12 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.MetaStoreUtils.newInstance(MetaStoreUtils.java:1521)
        ... 18 more
Caused by: javax.jdo.JDOFatalInternalException: Unexpected exception caught.
NestedThrowables:
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.invokeGetPersistenceManagerFactoryOnImplementation(JDOHelper.java:1193)
        at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.getPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOHelper.java:808)
        at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.getPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOHelper.java:701)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.getPMF(ObjectStore.java:365)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.getPersistenceManager(ObjectStore.java:394)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.initialize(ObjectStore.java:291)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.setConf(ObjectStore.java:258)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setConf(ReflectionUtils.java:73)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:133)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RawStoreProxy.<init>(RawStoreProxy.java:57)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RawStoreProxy.getProxy(RawStoreProxy.java:66)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.newRawStore(HiveMetaStore.java:593)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.getMS(HiveMetaStore.java:571)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.createDefaultDB(HiveMetaStore.java:624)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.init(HiveMetaStore.java:461)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.<init>(RetryingHMSHandler.java:66)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.getProxy(RetryingHMSHandler.java:72)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore.newRetryingHMSHandler(HiveMetaStore.java:5762)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient.<init>(HiveMetaStoreClient.java:199)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient.<init>(SessionHiveMetaStoreClient.java:74)
        ... 23 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at javax.jdo.JDOHelper$16.run(JDOHelper.java:1965)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.invoke(JDOHelper.java:1960)
        at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.invokeGetPersistenceManagerFactoryOnImplementation(JDOHelper.java:1166)
        ... 42 more
Caused by: org.datanucleus.exceptions.NucleusUserException: Persistence process has been specified to use a ClassLoaderResolver of name "datanucleus" yet this has not been found by the DataNucleus plugin mechanism. Please check your CLASSPATH and plugin specification.
        at org.datanucleus.NucleusContext.<init>(NucleusContext.java:283)
        at org.datanucleus.NucleusContext.<init>(NucleusContext.java:247)
        at org.datanucleus.NucleusContext.<init>(NucleusContext.java:225)
        at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.<init>(JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.java:416)
        at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.createPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.java:301)
        at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.getPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.java:202)
        ... 50 more
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: consequently you can conclude that you have not built the single jar correctly. plugin.xml from all DataNucleus jars you use would need merging and you won't have done that.

Comment: I'm using shade plugin XmlAppendingTransformer to merge these plugin.xml files together. Created file looks that there is content from all three datanucleus artifacts (but i don't know how to check if it's correct). I need to merge manifest files according to other questions. I tried to do it by hand but it just broke my build.

Comment: Hi, anebril. I met the same exception, followed your solutions, org.datanucleus.exceptions.NucleusUserException was solved, but met another one: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.jdo.JDOQLTypedQuery. Do you have any ideas about it? and my execute command is spark-submit --files files/hive-site.xml --jars lib/datanucleus-api-jdo-4.2.1.jar,lib/datanucleus-rdbms-4.1.7.jar,lib/datanucleus-core-4.1.6.jar target/tax-report-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar. I hope that you have contributed the codes in github. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have found solution to my problem. Solution is described in answer to original question for datanucleus in executable jar: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27030103/6390361

1. Edit **MANIFEST.MF** to pretend that it is datanucleus OSGi bundle. This can be done by adding **Bundle-SymbolicName** and **Premain-Class** entries from **datanucleus-core** manifest.
2. Create file plugin.xml in your classpath (resource folder) and use root tag from **datanucleus-core** project.
3. Put all **extension-point** tags from **datanucleus-core** and **datanucleus-rdbms** at the beginning of the plugin tag. All extension-points from RDBMS projects has to be prefixed with **store.rdbms**. This is very important because datanucleus uses fully classified IDs including part from root plugin tag.
4. Merge all **extension** tags from projects **datanucleus-core**, **datanucleus-rdbms** and **datanucleus-api-jdo** and put them behind all extension points. Be careful some extensions are present in more projects so you need to merge content of extensions with same IDs.

**Manifest entries**

```
Bundle-SymbolicName: org.datanucleus;singleton:=true
Premain-Class: org.datanucleus.enhancer.DataNucleusClassFileTransformer
```

**plugin.xml**

File plugin.xml is too big to be pasted here but you should be able to merge it by hand. Following code contains all RDBMS extension points with fixed IDs.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?eclipse version="3.2"?>    
<plugin id="org.datanucleus" name="DataNucleus Core" provider-name="DataNucleus">

    <!-- Extension points from datanucleus-core -->
    <extension-point id="api_adapter" name="Api Adapter" schema="schema/apiadapter.exsd"/>
    ...

    <!-- extension points from datanucleus-rdbms - fixed IDs -->
    <extension-point id="store.rdbms.connectionprovider" name="Connection Provider" schema="schema/connectionprovider.exsd"/>
    <extension-point id="store.rdbms.connectionpool" name="ConnectionPool" schema="schema/connectionpool.exsd"/>
    <extension-point id="store.rdbms.sql_expression" name="SQL Expressions" schema="schema/sql_expression.exsd"/>
    <extension-point id="store.rdbms.sql_method" name="SQL Methods" schema="schema/sql_method.exsd"/>
    <extension-point id="store.rdbms.sql_operation" name="SQL Expressions" schema="schema/sql_operation.exsd"/>
    <extension-point id="store.rdbms.sql_tablenamer" name="SQL Table Namer" schema="schema/sql_tablenamer.exsd"/>
    <extension-point id="store.rdbms.rdbms_mapping" name="RDBMS Mapping" schema="schema/rdbms_mapping.exsd"/>

    <!-- Merged extensions from datanucleus-core, datanucleus-rdbms and datanucleus-api-jdo -->
    <extension point="org.datanucleus.persistence_properties">...</extension>
    ...
</plugin>
```

**maven-shade-plugin**

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>shade</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <transformers>
                    <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                        <manifestEntries>
                            <Main-Class>${main.class}</Main-Class>
                            <Premain-Class>org.datanucleus.enhancer.DataNucleusClassFileTransformer</Premain-Class>
                            <Bundle-SymbolicName>org.datanucleus;singleton:=true</Bundle-SymbolicName>
                        </manifestEntries>
                    </transformer>
                    <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                        <resource>reference.conf</resource>
                    </transformer>
                    <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ServicesResourceTransformer"/>
                </transformers>
                <filters>
                    <filter>
                        <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                        <excludes>
                            <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                            <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                            <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                        </excludes>
                    </filter>
                </filters>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: I was facing similar issue while building Fat Jar from maven shade plugin, Only <manifestEntries> resolved my problem your solution was superb @anebril. Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Here is a link to a newer `plugin.xml`: https://pastebin.com/8b2deeCL build  out of these dependencies:

- `datanucleus-core-4.1.6`
- `datanucleus-rdbms-4.1.7`
- `datanucleus-api-jdo-4.2.1`

according to the answer by @anebril .

Answer (score 0):

Attempt to invoke the "HikariCP" plugin to create a ConnectionPool gave an error : The specified datastore driver ("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver") was not found in the CLASSPATH. Please check your CLASSPATH specification, and the name of the driver.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).