# DataNucleus on android: error on creating EntityManagerFactory

Tags: android, jpa, datanucleus

DataNucleus on android: After merging plugin.xml from api-jpa, rdbms, and core jars. Runtime error on creating EntityManagerFactory:

```
     Caused by: org.datanucleus.exceptions.NucleusException: 
Error creating handler of type "persistence" for metadata parsing : 
MetaData handler plugin "persistence" was not found. 
Please check your CLASSPATH and plugin specification.

at org.datanucleus.metadata.xml.MetaDataParser.parseMetaDataStream(MetaDataParser.java:276)

at org.datanucleus.metadata.xml.MetaDataParser.parseMetaDataURL(MetaDataParser.java:144)

at org.datanucleus.metadata.MetaDataUtils.parsePersistenceFiles(MetaDataUtils.java:863)

at org.datanucleus.api.jpa.JPAEntityManagerFactory.getPersistenceUnitMetaDataForName(JPAEntityManagerFactory.java:1316)

at org.datanucleus.api.jpa.JPAEntityManagerFactory.<init>(JPAEntityManagerFactory.java:410)

at org.datanucleus.api.jpa.PersistenceProviderImpl.createEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceProviderImpl.java:104)

at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:79)
```

Comment: sounds like you haven't merged it correctly.

Comment: After fixing manifest.mf, got different error at runtime: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45748223/datanucleus-duplicate-plugin-xml-in-multiple-jars-on-android?noredirect=1#comment78456113_45748223