# spring boot executable jar with datanucleus

Tags: java, spring-boot, datanucleus

A spring boot app that runs perfectly fine on the command line with:

```
mvn clean package spring-boot:run
```

I then add the spring boot plugin option to create an executable jar:

```
<plugin>
 <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
 <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <configuration>
    <executable>true</executable>
     <mainClass>for.bar.Application</mainClass>
     <layout>JAR</layout>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

and my app launches on the command line.  However, DataNucleus crashes with an error:

```
Could not find API definition for name "JDO". Perhaps you dont have the requisite datanucleus-api-XXX jar in the CLASSPATH?
```

The problem is partially explained here: [Datanucleus, JDO and executable jar - how to do it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10096772/datanucleus-jdo-and-executable-jar-how-to-do-it)

So I sort of understand what's happening. DataNuclues is an OSGi library. It it even possible to make a spring boot exec jar with DataNuclues as the persistence layer?  I'm about to try to switch to spring data which is going to be a nightmare.

Comment: I don't see DataNucleus as having any particular requirements, other than the user putting things in the CLASSPATH, since it is simply a Java process - OSGi is irrelevant to the argument ... so it is OSGi enabled, and?. You could read http://www.datanucleus.org/servlet/forum/viewthread_thread,8020_lastpage,yes#lastpost

Comment: thanks for the help Neil - i'm still working on this, in the link I posted in the question - datanuclues talks about how unpacking and repacking the dependencies breaks DN.  I've tried using different tools to make a fat jar with one jar or the maven assembly pluging but that ends up breaking spring boot.

Comment: Define how a single jar with correctly merged plugin.xml / MANIFEST.MF breaks Spring-boot. Who knows what Spring Boots requirement is

Comment: This post has one way someone merged it all ... for those that want to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37484239/apache-spark-hive-executable-jar-with-maven-shade  but you could check whether something is merged correctly before using it with Spring boot, so you know where the problem is

Comment: thanks again for all of the help - this was all a real mess between the spring boot maven plugin and DN - despite several attempts at using one-jar, the maven assembly plugin, and the various hacks in these threads I opted to backtrack and make my app into a war instead of an executable jar - then just installed tomcat and deployed the war which i'm happy with.  If i find a way to make an executable jar with spring boot / DN using maven plugins i'll update this thread.

Comment: Aaargh! Has anyone ever got DN to work in a fat Spring Boot jar?

Comment: oh man, i'm sorry to hear someone being stuck in the same place I was.  With all do respect to DN - I only chose that persistence layer because at the time I was targeting GAE.  I ended up rewriting my entire DAO in Spring Data / JPA and using the CrudRepository interfaces, which I'll tell you are delightful to work with after years of fighting the enhancer. However, building a WAR and installing to tomcat instead of making an executable jar had worked with DN as well.  Good luck!